# Django REST Framework - Serialize ForeignKey fields

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

In my app, users have a wall, similar to the old Facebook wall. A user is able to post comments on other users walls. I have a serializer with a base structure like this:

```
class UserWallCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserWallComment
        fields = ('uid', 'uidcommenter', 'idwall', 'created', 'description')
        read_only_fields = ('uid', 'uidcommenter', 'idwall', 'created')
```

`uid` and `uidcommenter` are foreignkeys to the user model, `idwall` is the PK, and `description` is the comment itself.

When a comment is created/edited, `uid` and `uidcommenter` needs to be set by the backend. A user can not be allowed to change these fields.

Lets say I have the variables `uid` and `uidcommenter` in my view that is calling the serializer - how can I pass these variables along to the serializer so that a UserWallComment is created?

I have tried setting `uid` and `uidcommenter` using the `SerializerMethodField` (passing the PK's in the context variable), but the database says I am passing NULL PK's:

```
class UserWallCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    uid = serializers.SerializerMethodField('setUid')
    class Meta:
        model = UserWallComment
        fields = ('uid', 'uidcommenter', 'idwall', 'created', 'description')
        read_only_fields = ('uidcommenter', 'idwall', 'created')
def setUid(self):
    return self.context['uid']
```

---

My view code (`idwall` is the pk of the wall):

```
class MemberWall(APIView):
    def post(self, request, requestUid, idwall):
        uid = request.user.uid
        serializer = UserWallCommentSerializer(data=request.DATA, context={'uid': requestUid, 'uidcommenter': uid})

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data['uid'], status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Are you using DRF's generic views? Can you post the view code?

Comment: OFC! I have posted the view code for post now.

Answer (score 1):

the documentation says that the `SerializerMethodField` is used only for [representation of the object](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). Which means it is used only when you return your data as a response.

By default the serializer get's the request passed:

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    """
    Extra context provided to the serializer class.
    """
    return {
        'request': self.request,
        'format': self.format_kwarg,
        'view': self
    }
```

This means that you can overwrite de default save, update methods of the [serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) and set the relevant fields. You should be able to access then using: `self._context.request.user.uid`

I didn't try this but it should work.

Comment: You are right, overwriting the save method would provide a solution. I could from there access the context variable, and add the uid and uidcommenter manually. 

The solution I however ended up with was to simply modify the incoming POST data. The data only contains the `description` variable, while I in my view add the `uid` and `uidcommenter` manually. I find this approach to be the most simple one, and easy to understand.

Thank you for answering!